# How to target entries in a Map of Lists?

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I'm trying to answer [this question about parsing data and sorting into bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368636/how-to-read-data-from-a-url-and-count-frequencies-into-bins-given-in-another-url). I think I almost have it solved but can't seem to get it to work properly.

Here's my code:

```
package soBins;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bins {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String rangeIn = "100 101 3.45\n101 102 4.23\n103 104 2.40\n199 200 6.89";

        String dataIn = "xx 108.45\nxx 122.00\nyy 124.78\nxx 156.93\nzz 101.5\nxx 103.5\nzz 101.25";

        Scanner rangeScanner = new Scanner(rangeIn);
        Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner(dataIn);  

        ArrayList<Bin> bins = new ArrayList<Bin>();
        while (rangeScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = rangeScanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            int min = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int max = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
//          System.out.println("Creating new bin, min "+ min + ", max "+ max);
            bins.add(new Bin(min,max));
        }

        Map<String,ArrayList<Bin>> namedBins = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Bin>>();
        while (dataScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = dataScanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String name = tokens[0]; // name is first token on line
            float data = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]); // data is second token on line

            if (!namedBins.containsKey(name)) {
                // Shouldn't this create a new copy of the ArrayList of bins??
                namedBins.put(name, new ArrayList<Bin>(bins));
            }
            for (Bin b : namedBins.get(name)) {
                if (b.isInRange(data)) {
                    System.out.println("adding "+ data + " to bin in "+ name);
                    b.addData(data);

                }
            }
        }   

        System.out.println("All bins and data contents:");
        for (String dataName : namedBins.keySet()) { // print all values and bin ranges
            for (Bin range : namedBins.get(dataName)) {
                System.out.println(dataName + ", min " + range.getMin() + ", max " + range.getMax()
                        + ", data is " + range.getData());              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Bin class:

```
package soBins;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bin {

    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    ArrayList<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();

    Bin(int min,int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public boolean isInRange(float data) {
        return (min < data) && (data < max);
    }

    public void addData(float data) {
        values.add(data);
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }
    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }
    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getData() {
        return values;
    }   

}
```

The output seems to be adding the data to every dataset, not just the one that it's meant to.

The output is:

```
adding 101.5 to bin in zz
adding 103.5 to bin in xx
adding 101.25 to bin in zz
All bins and data contents:
zz, min 100, max 101, data is []
zz, min 101, max 102, data is [101.5, 101.25]
zz, min 103, max 104, data is [103.5]
zz, min 199, max 200, data is []
yy, min 100, max 101, data is []
yy, min 101, max 102, data is [101.5, 101.25]
yy, min 103, max 104, data is [103.5]
yy, min 199, max 200, data is []
xx, min 100, max 101, data is []
xx, min 101, max 102, data is [101.5, 101.25]
xx, min 103, max 104, data is [103.5]
xx, min 199, max 200, data is []
```

Why is it adding to all groups, and not just to the intended one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create the `Bin` instances once and put them in the `bins` list prior to initializing the Map :

```
ArrayList<Bin> bins = new ArrayList<Bin>();
while (rangeScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    ....
    bins.add(new Bin(min,max));
}
```

and you use that same `bins` instance to initialize the value of all the keys of the Map :

```
namedBins.put(name, new ArrayList<Bin>(bins));
```

While this statement creates a new `ArrayList` for each `Map` entry, it puts in it the same `Bin` instances from the original `bins` List.
This means that the `Bin` instances in each `Bin` list in the Map are the same, so when you modify those `Bin` instances, you change all the `Map` entries.

In order to have unique `Bin` instances in each `Map` entry, you must have a copy constructor or clone method in the `Bin` class. Then you would do something like this :

```
if (!namedBins.containsKey(name)) {
    List<Bin> newBins = new ArrayList<Bin>();
    newdBins.put(name, new newBins);
    for (Bin bin : bins)
        newBins.add (new Bin(bin)); // using a copy constructor            
}
```